# Meaning of the $type parameter in socket_read()

Tags: php, sockets, php-5.3, unix-socket

I try to create a tcp/ip socket connection from a c# app to a PHP 5.3 script using PHP sockets. The c# app should send JSON strings to the PHP script.

My question in regard to [the socket_read manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php): What do they mean with:

```
"PHP_BINARY_READ (Default) - use the system recv() function.
Safe for reading binary data."
```

What exactly does PHP_BINARY_READ and why should I use the recv() function when using this parameter?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Because, you know, PHP didn't have *nearly enough* crack in it by the time they got to `socket_read()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part is what the documentation says about the *other* choice:

> - PHP_NORMAL_READ - reading stops at `\n` or `\r`.

Pick `PHP_NORMAL_READ` if your socket is a line-oriented text protocol. Pick `PHP_BINARY_READ` if your socket is anything else.

Comment: Ah! That's just a misunderstanding of their English; that is a statement that when you give that parameter, it is a command to PHP that it should use the underlying `recv()` system call to receive the data. _You_ don't have to do anything about it; it is again, a contrast to the higher-level line-oriented workings of the other parameter.

Comment: aha, got it! :-) I was confused because such a function actually exists in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php

Answer (score 4):

This means that when you use PHP_BINARY_READ then [this system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) will be used to read from the underlying socket. The remark about safety for binary data is explained by contrasting this with the alternative which [reads](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php)

> PHP_NORMAL_READ - reading stops at \n or \r.

Hence, if you would like to read one line at a time, then use PHP_NORMAL_READ. Otherwise, use PHP_BINARY_READ (which is default).